# How to read DOCX using Apache POI in page by page mode

Tags: java, apache-poi

I would like to read a docx files to search for a particular text. I would like the program to print the page on which it was found and the document name.
I have written this simple method, but it doesn't count any page:

```
     private static void searchDocx(File file, String searchText) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(fis);

        int pageNo = 1;
        for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : document.getParagraphs()) {

            String text = paragraph.getText();
            if (text != null) {
                if (text.toLowerCase().contains(searchText.toLowerCase())) {
                    System.out.println("found on page: " + pageNo+ " in: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
                }
            }
            if (paragraph.isPageBreak()) {
                pageNo++;
            }
        }
    }
```

How  to read the file, to be able to print the information on which page the searchText was found? Is there any way to know the page when reading the docx using ApachePOI?

Comment: "Is there any way to know the page when reading the docx using Apache POI?" No, not if there are not explicit page breaks are inserted. If your document would have explicit page breaks inserted then `isPageBreak()` would return `true` if one was found. If not, then the whole document is a steadily flow of paragraphs and how it will be splitted into different pages depends on rendering in Word using page settings and printer settings.

Comment: @Axel Richter Great answer, but Is there a way to count the splits of "height of paragraphs" and "pageBreaks" into actual page number? How to know how it would be rendered? Somehow the OpenOffice shows the information about the page on which we are currently, do you have any ideas?

Comment: "How to know how it would be rendered?" I'm afraid you can't. Only the GUI which is actually rendering the document will know that. And as said, even different default printers (having different non printable borders) will lead to different rendering results.